# CQL query throwing error: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (23)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-node-driver

Need help to resolve below issue.

```
Error:  ResponseError: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (23)\n
 at FrameReader.readError (D:\\EACApp\\eac-app-management\\node_modules\\cassandra-driver\\lib\\readers.js:326:15)\n
```

DB Query-

```
SELECT * FROM user_request_by_country_by_processworkflow \
    WHERE created_on <= ? (timestamp- 2022-07-26T15:39:52+05:30) 
    //passing as bind value

cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `created_on` column in the sample query you provided is a CQL `timestamp` type then there is no reason why the query wouldn't work.

I suspect that the underlying problem is that `created_on` is a different CQL type.

As a friendly note, I suggest you learn how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem.

In your case, you need to provide:

- the CQL table schema
- the driver you're using + version
- minimal sample code

If you don't provide sufficient information in your questions, you are less likely to get help from forums. Cheers!

Comment: Any solution to this because I am also facing same issue in my AdonisJs + Cassandra DB project